# Using while-loops instead of for-loops to create a 2D array for runtime efficiency

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, big-o, pseudocode

I have created the following code in Jana  (Java-Based Abstract Notation for Algorithms) which creates a 2-dimensional array of length n:

```
fillMatrix(↕int matrix[1:n,1:n], ↓int n, ↓int a){

for(i=1…n){
    for(j=1…n){
    if(abs(↓(i-j))<=a){
        matrix[i,j]=1
    }else{
        matrix[i,j]=0
    }
    }
}
}

int abs(↓int i){
    if(i<0)
        return –i
    else
        return i
}
```

This code has an asymptotic runtime of O(n^2).

My question is, assuming that each element of the matrix is initialized to 0 at the call, how can I make this code more efficient?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This is not about for-loops vs. while-loops. this is about algorithms. Ok, Now think about it. Your matrix has n^2 entries. What would be the minimal runtime of a single threaded program?

Comment: Switching from `for` loops to `while` loops by itself won't improve your running time, but it will make the code uglier and harder to read/maintain.  It seems that you need to touch every element in the matrix at least once for an assignment.  Well this is `O(n^2)` no matter how you slice it.

Comment: Well, in order to fill n^2 matrix cells, you need O(n^2) run time. The only way you can do better is if the number of 1s was significantly lower than the number of 0s, which would allow you to initialize just the cells that get 1 value (the rest would be 0 by default).

Comment: Just a side note why not use Math.abs(a) instead of defining your own method?

Comment: Because Jana does not include a function Math.abs(a)

Comment: What if we were to assume that each element of the matrix is initialized to 0. Could the code be made more efficient then?

Comment: Who is Jana? Java has Math.abs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have to initialize the cells that get 1 value (the rest of the cells are 0 by default):

If `a` is much smaller than `n`, you can initialize the cells that get 1 value in `O(n + a*n)` time.

For example, if a == 0, all you need is to set the n cells of the main diagonal of the matrix ((0,0),(1,0),...,(n-1,n-1)) to 1.

If a == 1, you need to set the `n` cells of the main diagonal + the `2*(n-1)` cells of the diagonal adjacent to the main diagonal.

...

If a = c, you need to set `O(n) + O(2c*n)` cells to `1`, which is `O(n + c*n)`.

To implement this algorithm, you'll need to replace your `O(n^2)` loop with `2*a+1` `O(n)` loops (one loop for each relevant diagonal).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you use the wrong tool for your problem. Not every problem is a nail, and so not every solution involves a hammer. If you create a `Matrix` interface, and program against that interface, you can solve the instantiation in `O(1)` and also use less memory:

```
interface Matrix {
    int get(int i, int j);
}

class OrdinaryMatrix implements Matrix {
    int[][] data;

    public OrdinaryMatrix (int rows, int columns) { ... }

    public int get(int i, int j) {
        return data[i][j];
    }
}

class SpecialMatrix implements Matrix {
    private final int a;
    public SpecialMatrix (int rows, int columns, int a) {
        ...
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int get(int i, int j) {
        return Math.abs(i-j)<=a ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but whether it is beneficial in terms of performance entirely depends on how that matrix is going to be used. If get(i,j) is going to be called multiple times for the same values of i & j, your lazy evaluation becomes less efficient. You could cache the cells computed by get(), though, to save the need to evaluate the same cell multiple times. If, however, all the cells of the matrix are going to be accessed after construction, a solution that doesn't require Math.abs() at all would be more efficient.

Comment: I doubt that caching the results will be any faster than re-evaluating in this simple case. Whatever you use for the cache, I bet that even finding the correct cache entry is more expensive than subtracting two integers and doing two integer comparisons.